# ModuleNotFoundError when installing a package with entry points using pipx

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pipx

I'm writing a python package that I would like to distribute as a standalone terminal app. The structure of the project folder is the following:

```
energy-monitor/
  config/
  doc/
  tests/
  energymonitor/
    __init__.py -> (empty)
    main.py -> def main()
    data/
    ..other packages..
  project.toml
```

I'm using setuptools to generate a .tar.gz archive, some relevant parts of the project.toml file are:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=68.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "energy-monitor"
version = "0.0.1"

...

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["energymonitor"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
data = ["data/*"]

[project.scripts]
energy-monitor = "energymonitor.main:main"
```

I generate the .tar.gz and the .whl files with the command `python -m build`, then I run `pipx install path/to/energy-monitor.tar.gz`. The installation is succesful, but when calling `energy-monitor` from the command line I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mattia/.local/bin/energy-monitor", line 5, in <module>
    from energymonitor.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'energymonitor'
```

Why is this happening? I was not able to find any helpful solution online. It's the first that I build a python package so sorry if the issue is trivial.

- python version: 3.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From setuptools' [docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages),
I'd take it that the `where` value in `[tool.setuptools.packages.find]` is the search path your packages should be found inside. You gave it the package folder directly, which should probably be done like this:

```ini
[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["energymonitor"]
```

As a result, the `energymonitor` package never actually ended up in your build, which you can easily verify by unpacking it.

Answer (score -1):

The package name is "energy-monitor", but the module name is "energymonitor". This causes the "ModuleNotFoundError" when you try to run the installed package.

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["energy_monitor"] << Package Name

from energy_monitor.main import main << How it should look like

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made the changes you suggested and changed the both the package name and the module name into energy_monitor, but I still get the same error.

Comment: The package name is in fact `energymonitor` as OP stated.
The `project.name` is `energy-monitor`, but that's only what you have to use to `pip install` it or when specifying it as a dependency, **NOT** when importing it.
`where` also needs the name of a source folder to look up packages, while `energy_monitor` exists nowhere in OPs folder structure.
So all in all, there's zero correct information in this post.